# Skeleton Directory: Why does script fail when nosetests returns no errors?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, nose

(Using bash command line, Python 2.7.12 on Debian Linux.)

Following Zed Shaw's LPTHW, I built a project skeleton that helps with testing software. First, the outline.

The setup:

```
    bin  docs  first_project  setup.py  tests

./bin:

./docs:

./first_project:
__init__.py  wasp.py

./tests:
first_project_tests.py  __init__.py
```

Contents of wasp.py:

```
def paint(color):
    print color * 10
```

Contents of first_projects_tests.py:

```
from nose.tools import *
from first_project import wasp

def test_paint():
    wasp.paint("blue")
```

Per my understanding of Zed Shaw's explanation, the `__init__.py` in the first_project directory tells Python that the files in it can be imported as modules. Thus the script first_project_tests.py in the test directory imports the wasp.py module from the first_project directory and calls the paint function from it.

Following Shaw's directions, I ran nosetests from above the tests directory and I got an ok with zero errors.

I then changed into the tests directory and typed python first_project_tests.py from the command line, assuming that I'd be able to run the script with no issues as the nosetests command gave no errors.

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "first_project_tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    from first_project import wasp
ImportError: No module named first_project
```

So why does the first_project_tests.py script fail when nosetests returns no errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python imports work relative from the *module search path*. The current directory is automatically included on this path.

When you run the `nosetests` at the top level of your project, the `first_project` module with `wasp` inside is found at the relative path, since `first_project/wasp.py` exists relative from the execution directory.

When you go inside `tests` and try to run `first_project_tests.py`, the import statement fails because the relative path `first_project/wasp.py` doesn't exist from inside that directory.

You could run from the project root like this:

```
python tests/first_project_tests.py
```